# Data is not splitting by row level

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Data is not splitting by row level when converting the correct xml from the given xslt and Data is continuing in single row in csv/text.

Tried with line feed & code but data is not displaying properly.

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/HFC">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Related_Calculated_Time_Blocks>
            <wd:Workday_ID>26b15207b31981e8759</wd:Workday_ID>
            <wd:Time_Block>8 HOURS ON 01/01/2019</wd:Time_Block>
            <wd:Worker>ABC</wd:Worker>
            <wd:Employee_ID>100</wd:Employee_ID>
            <wd:Reported_Date>2019-01-01</wd:Reported_Date>
            <wd:Time_Entry_Code>Adjust Holiday Hours</wd:Time_Entry_Code>
            <wd:Unit>Hours</wd:Unit>
            <wd:Calculated_Quantity>1.78923</wd:Calculated_Quantity>
            <wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance>Holiday</wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance>
            <wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance__Numeric_>111</wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance__Numeric_>
            <wd:Source>User Entered</wd:Source>
        </wd:Related_Calculated_Time_Blocks>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Related_Calculated_Time_Blocks>
            <wd:Workday_ID>f3b6c47bca118110</wd:Workday_ID>
            <wd:Time_Block>8 HOURS ON 01/01/2019</wd:Time_Block>
            <wd:Worker>DEF</wd:Worker>
            <wd:Employee_ID>101</wd:Employee_ID>
            <wd:Reported_Date>2019-01-01</wd:Reported_Date>
            <wd:Time_Entry_Code>Adjust Holiday Hours</wd:Time_Entry_Code>
            <wd:Unit>Hours</wd:Unit>
            <wd:Calculated_Quantity>8</wd:Calculated_Quantity>
            <wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance>Holiday</wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance>
            <wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance__Numeric_>111</wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance__Numeric_>
            <wd:Source>User Entered</wd:Source>
        </wd:Related_Calculated_Time_Blocks>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

*******************XSLT**************************

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/HFC">

    <xsl:output method="text"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>


    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <File xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday.report/HFC" xtt:quotes="csv" xtt:separator="&#xD;&#xA;">
            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Related_Calculated_Time_Blocks">
                <Record xtt:separator="&#9;" xtt:quotes="csv">
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Workday_ID"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="1"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Reported_Date"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>

                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:EE_Calculation_Tag_is_Single_Instance"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="''"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>

                    <xsl:value-of select="''"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>

                    <xsl:value-of select="''"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>

                    <xsl:value-of select="''"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Calculated_Quantity"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Quantity'"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Reported_Date"/> 
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'DELLL'"/> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
                </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i am expecting the data in row level but it is continuing in column level:

Comment: Your question is confusing -- you say that you are _"converting xml to xslt"_.  This doesn't make any sense.  One uses XSLT to convert XML into something else (usually, other XML).  Also, you might have made a copy-paste error, as your top and bottom code samples are both XML (neither shows XSLT), and the two are nearly identical.  Please edit your post to provide a [**minimal and reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i gave the correct xslt now.

Comment: What would your desired outcome look like?

Comment: Which tool exactly do you use? How does the result look you want, how does the current result look? The use of attributes like `xtt:quotes="csv" xtt:separator="&#xD;&#xA;"` and `xtt:separator="&#9;" xtt:quotes="csv"` suggests some part of your transformation to CSV is not done by standard XSLT code but by some proprietary extension. Unless you explain which that is and add a tag for it so that other users of that tool see the question it might be hard to find someone who knows that stuff.